# Função PHP selecionar 2 valores

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Boas!

Eu estou a criar funções em PHP com o objectivo de retornar a diferença entre a data `TIMESTAMP` da base de dados e a data de hoje, e para isso criei duas funções:

```
function getRegistos()
{
    $query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),dataDeEntrada) as diferenca FROM `equipamentos` WHERE 1";
    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
    return $res;
}

function getData()
{
    $query = "SELECT (dataDeEntrada2), DATEDIFF(NOW(),dataDeEntrada2) as diferencaTotais FROM `equipamentos` WHERE 1";
    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
    return $res;
}
```

A `getRegistos()` serve para ir buscar os registos e os dias decorridos e a `getData()` serve apenas para conseguir os dias totais desde que o produto foi registado ( porque quando o administrador actualiza um produto a coluna dataDeEntrada volta ao 0 ).

Não sei se é possível juntar as duas ou então chama-las de maneira diferente...

```
include_once('DataAccess.php');
            $da = new DataAccess();
            $res = $da->getRegistos();
            $res1 = $da->getData();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){ ... }
```

Mas só me retorna o `getRegistos()`. Também tentei fazer outro while mas desta vez com `$res1` que é o valor retornado pelo `getData()` mas nada feito.
Sou novo em PHP e acredito que eu apenas esteja a complicar.

Comment: Acho que você está complicando as coisas. Veja: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a677a/1

Comment: O link que enviou não funciona.
Na tabela Equipamentos tenho as seguintes colunas:
ID, id_utilizador, nome, tipo, estado, dataDeEntrada, dataDeEntrada2, marca, modelo, sintoma, orcamento

Comment: Funciona, só esperar um pouco. Pelo ao menos pra mim funciona.

Comment: Ok hoje consegui abrir.
Isso foi o que eu fiz.
Mas eu queria guardar 2 diferenças. Uma para os dias decorridos e outra para os dias Totais pois uma vai ser resetada e outra não por isso é que tenho 2 dataDeEntrada na base de dados.

Comment: Entendi, na segunda você pode usar `SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(NOW(), d2)) AS TOTAL FROM t;` isso de acordo com meu SQLFIDDLE.

Comment: Exatamente, mas isso implicaria criar outra função.

Comment: Mas isso foi o que ja fiz. Agora o problema é chamar as duas. Como pode ver eu usei um while para mostrar todas as informações da tabela equipamentos. Agora preciso de outro apenas para mostrar os dias totais.

Comment: Entendi, desculpe o mal entendimento. Mais chama o GetRegistros e não Chama o GetData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resolvido**

Única coisa que mudei foi a chamar as funções.

Pois eu chamava-as assim:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
include_once('DataAccess.php');
$da = new DataAccess();
$res = $da->getEquipamento($id);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){ ... }
```

E a única coisa que faltava era isto:

```
$res1 = $da->getData();
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_object($res1);
```

Ou seja, ficou assim:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
include_once('DataAccess.php');
$da = new DataAccess();
$res = $da->getEquipamento($id);
$res1 = $da->getData();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_object($res1);
... 
}
```